# Can I take a screenshot and directly open it in Gimp?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gimp, screenshot

Common use case for me and printscreen:

- Hit printscreen and save `.png`
- Open up `Gimp`
- Find file I've saved
- Edit file (crop and highlight regions)

It seems like the first three steps could be combined into a single key bind, e.g. printscreen auto opens `Gimp`, ready to edit. Is that possible?

Comment: Can very well be done. Are you always storing the images on the same location?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I can, though in 99% of these cases I discard the images after I upload them somewhere. Think highlighting something on a screenshot for a git issue or a stack exchange question.

Comment: I think saving to clipboard is perfectly fast enough for me. PrintScreen-copy-to-clipboard (probably Ctrl-Shift-PrtSc?), open Gimp, Ctrl-Shift-V. Done.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/994235/from-screenshot-to-edit-image

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Quick version

Literally doing what you asked; in one action:

- Take a screenshot
- Save it in your preferred directory
- Opening it with Gimp

  [image]

#### The script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

picsdir=~/Pictures/out.png
gnome-screenshot -f "$picsdir"
gimp "$picsdir"
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `take_ashot.sh`
- Set your preferred directory to save the files in, in the line:

  ```
  picsdir=~/Pictures/out.png
  ```

  I'd leave it as it is if your system is English, else you'd need to change the Pictures folder name.
- Test-run it by the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash /path/to/take_ashot.sh
  ```
- If all works fine, add it to a shortcut: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
  /bin/bash /path/to/take_ashot.sh
  ```

#### Note

Since you mentioned *not* to save the source file in most cases, I made the script overwrite previous files. If you don't want that, we'd need to build in a few renaming- lines.

Comment: Nice. I think I'd put it in `/tmp`, though.

Comment: @TRiG good idea! Thanks Jacob, the script with the keyboard shortcuts work perfectly!

Answer (score 10):

Why not just take the screenshot *with* Gimp? File > Create > Screenshot.

[image]

This requires no intermediate storage at all.

Comment: Execution error for 'Screenshot':
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: No such object path '/Screenshot'

Comment: Luis:  Solution for that issue is to invoke with "dbus-launch".  Just precede gimp in the invocation with "dbus-launch".  For normal interactive usage from CLI you'd just run: dbus-launch gimp &

Comment: Hopefully there's a "proper" DBus fix, rather than just `dbus-launch`ing GIMP! The built-in screenshotting is so useful.

Answer (score 5):

With `xfce4-screenshooter` you can choose from programs to open screenshot with, or save it. Supports selecting area, delay before taking screenshot. Directly point-and-click solution.

[image: xfce4-screenshooter screen]

Answer (score 4):

For **xfce** and **Xubuntu** users, the action can be achieved with the following command:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -f -o gimp
```

To implement, change the shortcut in Settings -> Keyboard, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to switch screenshot applications, this is an option that [`scrot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/scrot.1.html) provides:

```
   -e, --exec APP
        Exec APP on the saved image.
…
EXAMPLE
       scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h.png' -e 'mv $f ~/shots/'
       This would create a file called something like 2000-10-30_2560x1024.png
       and move it to your shots directory.
```

So, you could change the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> shortcut to run:

```
scrot -e 'gimp $f'
```

---

Shutter, another screenshot application, provides some editing facilities itself, so you might not even need to start GIMP at all.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Gnome then you can use the built-in screenshot shortcuts to at least bypass the "save to disk and open the file" step.

1. Press the appropriate "to clipboard" shortcut (basically the standard "save to file" shortcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>):

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to capture a window
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to capture an area
2. Open GIMP
3. If there are no images open in GIMP, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes as a new image

The shortcuts are configurable in Gnome Settings under Keyboard > View and customise shortcuts > Screenshots.

[image: Screenshot of Gnome Settings for screenshotting]

I've disabled saving screenshots because I use custom shortcuts with `gnome-screenshot` to save to `~/temp/` rather than `~/Pictures/` (because I care about Pictures but not about anything in temp, like random screenshots)

Answer (score -1):

For Linux Mint version Mate, just run the commands below to configure your system once and press the PrtScn on your keyboard.

```
sudo apt install scrot
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings run-command-screenshot "disabled"
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom0/action \'"scrot -e \"gimp \$f\""\'
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom0/binding \'Print\'
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom0/name \'PrintScreen\'
```

The screenshot will be saved in your home folder at ~/ if you don't want them there, you can always use this below to move the screenshot in the /tmp folder:

```
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/keybindings/custom0/action \'"scrot -e \"mv \$f /tmp; gimp /tmp/\$f\""\'
```