# Looking for Ubuntu 20.04 screenshot editor integration!

Tags: 20.04, gnome-screenshot

In Ubuntu 20.04 (at least my upgraded system) there is now a default screenshot tool, blue icon with some dots ... which I actually really like!

I have had trouble with Shutter already before the upgrade, and am looking for a way to very directly edit a screenshot after taking it with this new cool default tool ― just a lightweight image editor for cropping and pixelizing areas, like the one that Shutter used to integrate with. Do you have a quick recipe for how to integrate any such tool into the default screenshot tool?

Or a standalone such lightweight tool that starts quickly when launched?

With Shutter there was a great screenshot editor integrated, but it took a whole procedure to setup, and (maybe in my own fault) Shutter stopped working cleanly for me at some point.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From Screenshot to "edit Image"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994235/from-screenshot-to-edit-image). Check out the application mentioned in the accepted answer other that Shutter. It's called "Flameshot", it's lightweight and quite popular nowadays.

Comment: @pomsky does Flameshot allow editing of *existing* images?

Comment: @DKBose Probably not, given that it's a dedicated screenshot tool.

Comment: @pomsky thanks. they suggest Shutter. I think there was a nightmare procedure to setup or fix-up its image editor integration last I tried after updates / upgrade. Maybe I'll try again, if it's not integrated elegantly in the 20.04 native gnome screenshot tool.

Comment: Check out the application mentioned in the accepted answer **other than** Shutter.

Comment: As for shutter, this Ubuntu 20.04 oriented blog post seems to imply you might get a sane setup of Shutter installed using a snap: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/07/install-shutter-on-ubuntu-20-04-snap

Comment: There's also a Shutter PPA which enables all Shutter plugins: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/shutter-removed-from-ubuntu-1810-and.html